# Parsing yaml file and getting a dictionary

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'd like to be able to take the YAML defined below and turn it into a dictionary.

```
development:
    user:dev_uid
    pass:dev_pwd
    host:127.0.0.1
    database:dev_db

production:
    user:uid
    pass:pwd
    host:127.0.0.2
    database:db
```

I have been able to use the YAML library to load the data in. However, my dictionary appears to contain the environmental items as a long string.

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import yaml

config  = yaml.load(open('database.conf', 'r'))

print(config['development'])
```

yields the following output.

```
user:dev_uid pass:dev_pwd host:127.0.0.1 database:dev_db
```

I can't access any of the entries by key name or load that string subsequent using the `yaml.load` method.

```
print(config['development']['user'])
```

This code yields the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Ideally I would like to end up with a parsing function that returns a dictionary or a `list` so I can access the properties by key name or using the `dot` operator like:

```
print(config['development']['user'])
config.user
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unless you are using tags that specify Python internal objects (which almost nobody does) there is no need to use `yaml.load()` which is documented to be unsafe. Always use `yaml.safe_load()` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your "yaml" is not a mapping of mappings, it's a mapping of strings.  In YAML 1.2, block mapping entries [need whitespace after the separator](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#:%20mapping%20value//), e.g.

```
development:
    user: dev_uid
    pass: dev_pwd
    host: 127.0.0.1
    database: dev_db

production:
    user: uid
    pass: pwd
    host: 127.0.0.2
    database: db
```

Don't try to pre-process this text.  Instead, find who generated the markup and [throw the spec at them](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2798057).

Comment: That would be me. :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've been flumoxxed by this since last week - this is the first YAML item I've seen that mentions _anything_ about the importance of whitespace! I had no clue from others I've read......

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not getting what you want with the `yaml` module immediately, your .conf file is probably using a format different than what the `yaml` module currently expects.

This code is a quick workaround that gives you the dictionary you want:

```
for mainkey in ['production','development']:
    d = {}
    for item in config[mainkey].split():
        key,value = item.split(':')
        d[key] = value
    config[mainkey] = d
```

Answer (score -2):

Your YAML is absolutely valid, and that is why you won't get an error when loading this. That it doesn't load as you expect is because YAML has a feature to wrap (long) lines at whitespace and this works for unquoted scalars such as your

```
user:dev_uid
pass:dev_pwd
host:127.0.0.1
database:dev_db
```

Your YAML file is equivalent to:

development: "user:dev_uid pass:dev_pwd host:127.0.0.1 database:dev_db"
   production: "user:uid pass:pwd host:127.0.0.2 database:db"

and to

development: user:dev_uid pass:dev_pwd host:127.0.0.1 database:dev_db
   production: user:uid pass:pwd host:127.0.0.2 database:db

as quotes are not necessary, since there can be no confusion about the value for `development` to be a mapping, as for that the colon after the key should be followed by a space. This can be seen from the older (now outdated) [YAML 1.1 specification](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2545757) that was used to implement PyYAML¹.

Best is to convert, correct the YAML which can be easily done if you can assume that none of the keys and values have embedded spaces:

```
import sys
import yaml


yaml_str = """\
development:
    user:dev_uid
    pass:dev_pwd
    host:127.0.0.1
    database:dev_db

production:
    user:uid
    pass:pwd
    host:127.0.0.2
    database:db
"""

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
for key in data:
    val = data[key]
    if ':' not in val:
        continue
    data[key] = tmp = {}
    for x in val.split():
        x = x.split(':', 1)
        tmp[x[0]] = x[1]

yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

If your file is more complicated that what you presented, you might have to recurs into dict values and list items, which is fairly trivial.

The above outputs:

```
development:
  database: dev_db
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pass: dev_pwd
  user: dev_uid
production:
  database: db
  host: 127.0.0.2
  pass: pwd
  user: uid
```

which then loads as you expect without the hassle.

---

¹<sub>The newer YAML 1.2 allows key-value pairs without a space after the colon when using flow-style mappings. But the pre-requisite for that is that both key and value are (double) quoted. This change was necessary to allow YAML 1.2 compatibility with JSON:</sub>

```
development: {
    "user":"dev_uid",
    "pass":"dev_pwd",
    "host":"127.0.0.1",
    "database":"dev_db"
  }
```